# SQL statement group data from multiple tables under one

Tags: mysql, sql

I was not sure how to phrase my question as I am new to SQL. It should not be too hard. Here is the scenario.

I have 3 tables:

**customers**

```
id, 
contact
```

**subscribers_from_x**

```
customer_id
 subscriber_name
```

**subscribers_from_y**

```
customer_id,
subscriber_name
```

here is the question:

Now, I want to select

**customer.id**

**the number of times/count of customer.id occurs in subscribers_from_x**

**the number of times/count of customer.id occurs in subscribers_from_y**

from these 3 tables

I have tried `GROUP_BY COUNT(*)` but not figuring it out. THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might go with using two separate subqueries which aggregate counts by subscriber for the x and y tables:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.contact,
       COALESCE(t2.x_count, 0) AS subscribers_from_x,
       COALESCE(t3.y_count, 0) AS subscribers_from_y
FROM customers t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) AS x_count
    FROM subscribers_from_x
    GROUP BY customer_id
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.customer_id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) AS y_count
    FROM subscribers_from_y
    GROUP BY customer_id
) t3
    ON t1.id = t3.customer_id
```

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, subquery might lead to performance issue right?,  I usually prefer join over subquery. Please let me know so that i'll move forward in proper direction

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(users.id),count(x.customer_id) 'X count',count(y.customer_id) 'Y Count'
       FROM customers 
          LEFT  JOIN subscribers_from_x x ON customers.id = x.customer_id
          LEFT  JOIN subscribers_from_y y ON customers.id = y.customerid
        GROUP BY customers.id,subscribers_from_x.pk_col -- primary key col of subscribers_from_x
```

It will give you required output

Comment: This method may result in double counting, if a given customer appears multiple times in each of the x and y tables.

Comment: yeah, that's why used 'group by customers.id,subscribers_from_x.pk_col'

Comment: If you want to do this in a single join with no subquery, you will need to find a way around the duplicate counting problem.  I agree that subqueries aren't optimal, but there is a time and place for them.  This is probably one such time and place.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, and you also probably should not be using it along with `GROUP BY`.